# Error when upgrading from CocoaPods 0.39 to 1.1.1

Tags: cocoapods, cocoapods-1.1.1, cocoapods-0.39.0

I'm trying to upgrade to the latest version of CocoaPods, but I'm running into an error. My previous `Podfile` looked something like this:

```
target 'myapp-ios' do
  link_with *%w[myapp-dev myapp-qa myapp-prod]
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6.3'
  # ...
end
```

Now it looks like this:

```
abstract_target 'myapp-ios' do
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6.3'
  # ...

  target 'myapp-dev' do
  end

  target 'myapp-qa' do
  end

  target 'myapp-prod' do
  end
end
```

When I try and build my app, I get this error:

> ld: framework not found Pods_myapp_ios
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It seems like it gets through compiling all of the CocoaPods as well as my app code, then it fails near the end. I'm not sure if this is somehow a reference to the old Podfile or if this has something to do with the new `abstract_target` (or even something unreleated to both of those things).

I did notice that in the clang command output, it lists both `-framework Pods_myapp_ios -framework Pods_myapp_ios_myapp_qa` when I try to build my `qa` target.

What steps should I take to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. While inspecting the settings of one of my targets, I noticed in the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section that it listed `Pods_myapp_ios.framework` as a required framework. I'm guessing this is left over from the previous version.

I removed it and it seems like my app is now building as expected.